# Ridge regression in glmnet in R; Calculating VIF for different lambda values using glmnet package

Tags: r, regression, modeling, glmnet

I have a set of multicollinear variables and I'm trying to use ridge regression to tackle that. I am using the `glmnet` package in R with alpha = 0 (for ridge regression).

```
library(glmnet)
```

I have a sequence of lambda values, and I am choosing the best lambda value through cv.glmnet

```
lambda <- 10^seq(10, -2, length = 100)
```

-- creating model matrix and assigning the y variable

```
x <- model.matrix(dv ~ ., datamatrix) [,-1]
y <- datamatrix$dv
```

-- Using cross validation to determine the best lambda and predicting y using that lambda value

```
ridge.mod <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda)
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)
ridge.pred <- predict(ridge.mod, s = cv.out$lambda.min, newx = x)
```

I am able to successfully do till this point, but I have to also check for the VIF for this particular lambda value to ensure that the coefficients have stabilized and the multicollinearity is controlled. But I am not sure how to check for VIF in GLMNET since the usual `vif()` function throws this error.

> Error in vcov.default(mod) : 
>     there is no vcov() method for models of class elnet, glmnet

Could you please help me identify if there is anything wrong in my approach or how to solve this issue?

Is VIF not applicable for validation in GLMNET?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VIF is a property of set of independent variables only. It doesn't matter what dependent variable is and what kind of model you use (linear regression, generalized model) as long as it doesn't change indeperndent variables (as e.g. additive model does). See `vif` function from `car` package. So, VIF applied to elastic net regression, won't tell you if you have dealt with multicollinearity. It can just tell you that there was a multicollinearity to deal with.

Comment: I think it is not what OP asked for. She/he had already chosen a model using glmnet (she/he picked lambda (k) parameter). So she/he asks for VIF from one particular set of dependent variables. You showed that VIF changes with rigde constant. Of course it does since number of variables in model changes with rigde contant. Just like I wrote: VIF is a property of set of independent variables only.

Answer (score 2):

Hadi Regression Analysis by Examples (p295) has the following ridge regression definition of the VIF. Z is the standardized version of the covariate matrix.

[image: VIF for Ridge]

Comment: any example of this in R?

Answer (score -1):

The library: [genridge](https://github.com/friendly/genridge) allows you to fit a ridge model and compute the vif for the model parameters.

Also relevant is this [document](https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2019/3109-2019.pdf), see page 13 that explains a bit more the type of analysis you could make.

Here is an example based on genridge::vif.ridge. You can compare a linear model with a ridge regression and plot how the VIF decreases as you use more regularization.
See ?vif.ridge for more examples

```
data(longley)
lmod <- lm(Employed ~ GNP + Unemployed + Armed.Forces + Population + 
             Year + GNP.deflator, data=longley)
vif(lmod)

longley.y <- longley[, "Employed"]
longley.X <- data.matrix(longley[, c(2:6,1)])

lambda <- c(0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08)
lridge <- ridge(longley.y, longley.X, lambda=lambda)
coef(lridge)

vridge <- vif(lridge)
vridge

# plot VIFs
pch <- c(15:18, 7, 9)
clr <- c("black", rainbow(5, start=.6, end=.1))

matplot(rownames(vridge), vridge, type='b', 
        xlab='Ridge constant (k)', ylab="Variance Inflation", 
        xlim=c(0, 0.08), 
        col=clr, pch=pch, cex=1.2)
text(0.0, vridge[1,], colnames(vridge), pos=4)
```

[image]

Comment: I show that VIF changes as the lambda changes. The idea is to understand the relation between regularization and VIF. You probably can adapt the library to work with GLMNET with alpha=0. You can read the source of genridge::vif.ridge, it's different from car's version as it's for a different model.